# Get function object property from within function

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, functions can have properties. Like this:

```
var f = function(){ console.log("Hello!"); }
f.x = "Whoohoo";
```

How do I retrieve `x` from code within `f()` that might be called long after the variable f goes out of scope?

Comment: If you're within the body of function `f`, how is it possible for it to be "out of scope"? Just use `f.x` in the body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors), like the assignment.

```js
var f = function() { console.log("Hello! " + f.x); }
f.x = "Whoohoo";

console.log(f.x);
f();
```

For stable access, you could use a named function

```js
var f = function foo() { console.log("Hello! " + foo.x); }
//               ^^^ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ^^^
f.x = "Whoohoo";

console.log(f.x);
f();
```

Comment: You misunderstood; I want to get the property from code within the function itself, not from the code that surrounds it.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev, it is stil the property accessor. for a static reference, i suggest to use a named function.

Comment: Works. It wasn't immediately obvious to me that the closure logic would capture the function variable, since it hasn't been assigned at the time of function creation.

Comment: Nice - using a named function would be preferable to the function referencing `f`

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev Closures do capture bindings (variables), not the values that they contain when the closure is created.

Answer (score 0):

If you need some more robust (but also more verbose):

```
var f = (function(){
    var func = () => {
        console.log(func.a)
    }
    return func
})()
f.a = 'Whoohoo'

// trying to break it
var a = f
f = 'somethingelse'
a()
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you're looking for is to simply access that property from within your function f, you simply reference the function object (either by the variable name if it's a function expression, or by the function name if it's a function declaration).

For example:

```
var f = function(){ return f.x; };
f.x = "Whoohoo";

// f() => "Whoohoo"

var b = function(){ return f.x; ];

// b() => "Whoohoo"
```

However, your mention of calling f "long after the variable f goes out of scope" contradicts the lexical scoping of JavaScript. You cannot call the function f unless you do so from the same scope where the function was defined, or from a child scope in reference to where the function was defined. If you are "out of scope", invoking f will throw a reference error.

Comment: `setTimeout(f, 1);`

Answer (score 0):

Let's get a little convoluted. `f` is already the name of the function by the expression that defines it. And a function is an object by definition in JS. So you can access it and it's properties (such as `x`) through the `f` keyword like `f.x`. Yet, since `f` is a function, you may use the it as a constructor too and do silly things like...

```js
var f = function(){ console.log("Hello!"); };
f.x = "Whoohoo";

f.prototype.thingy = function(){
  console.log(this.constructor.x);
};

var a = new f();
a.thingy();
```

... and from this point on lets get a little more convoluted. You might event do;

```js
function F(){
  F.prototype.thingy = function(){
                         return this.constructor.x;
                       };
  var obj = Object.create(F.prototype);
  console.log("Hello!");
  return obj.thingy();
}


F.x = "Whoohoo";

console.log(F());
```

So you can get the value of a property of the function object `F` "*from within itself*" by taking an object instantiated by itself under a closure.